# Facilitate progress or process

Tags: word-usage

When I'm following up with someone about something, i would like to ask if there's anything I can do to make it faster. Should I use "facilitate the progress" or "facilitate the process"? Or there's no big deal to use either of it?

Comment: You can facilitate either progress or process, though the latter is more likely. What do dictionary entries suggest about the difference between the two?

Comment: _Facilitate_ means to make something easier, not faster. Facilitation may improve speed, or it may not, depending on what gets facilitated and how the system works.

Comment: Has "help" gone out of fashion?

Comment: @Davo _Help_ means to make something easier (for those trying to achieve something), not (necessarily) faster. Has 'speed up' ... er ...? // But 'speed up progress' and 'speed up _the_ process' show that English likes to have the last word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second what John said. You typically say "to facilitate the process" rather than "facilitate progress," but the two phrases have different meanings. If you were wanting to facilitate the progress of a system, goal or process, it may make more sense to use the term "expedite" or to [assist the progress of a process](https://www.crosswordsolver.com/clue/ASSIST-PROGRESS-OF-PROCESS). If you were wanting to [permit or facilitate achievement or accomplishment](https://www.crosswordsolver.com/clue/A-QUALITY-THAT-PERMITS-OR-FACILITATES-ACHIEVEMENT-OR-ACCOMPLISHMENT) towards a goal, you could alternatively use the action-oriented term "enable."